# Integer.parseint() Fails with Input String Greater than 9

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to int by using Integer.parseInt() - This works fine up to an input string of "9" but fails when the input string reaches 10:

```
System.out.println("PROBLEM INT Chars:" + bf2Tokens[0].trim());
System.out.println("PROBLEM INT Bytes:" + bf2Tokens[0].trim().getBytes());
int n = Integer.parseInt(bf2Tokens[0].trim());
```

The output:

```
PROBLEM INT Chars:10
PROBLEM INT Bytes:[B@4f57011e
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at Index.main(Index.java:281)
```

I have also tried Integer.valueOf() without success.

Any suggestions what might be occurring here?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Well `Integer.parseInt("10")` works fine, so your string probably has other junk in it besides `"10"`.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. I strongly suspect you've got some unprintable character in there.

Comment: You've a bug in code not shown. Please extract your problem -- create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could use Arrays.asList("10".chars().boxed().toArray()) to make the exact characters visible if you're not using an old version.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with special(unprintable) character

here is output from your question itself. Please have a look again at the value of `bf2Tokens[0]`.

There is some special(unprintable) character in the string as shown in below output that is posted by you.

```
PROBLEM INT Chars:1�0
PROBLEM INT Bytes:[B@4f57011e
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1�0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at Index.main(Index.java:281)
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran this code, which I derived from yours because the code you posted is incomplete.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] bf2Tokens = new String[] { "10" };

        System.out.println("PROBLEM INT Chars:" + bf2Tokens[0].trim());
        System.out.println("PROBLEM INT Bytes:" + bf2Tokens[0].trim().getBytes());
        int n = Integer.parseInt(bf2Tokens[0].trim());

        System.out.println("n: " + n);
    }
}
```

It runs without exception and I get the following output:

```
PROBLEM INT Chars:10
PROBLEM INT Bytes:[B@2a788b76
n: 10
```

As you can see, I set `bf2Tokens[0]` to the value "10" and it works perfectly.  Thus, contrary to what you think, `bf2Tokens[0]` in your program is not equal to "10".  It may look like 10, but it isn't.  Try printing quotes around it like so:

```
System.out.println("PROBLEM INT Chars:'" + bf2Tokens[0].trim() + ');
```

That will help reveal any leading or trailing characters.  I also suggest outputting the length of the string.

```
System.out.prinln("length: " + bf2Tokens[0].trim().length());
```

Because you are using wrapping the string you parse in `.trim()`, clearly you don't have a leading or trailing space.  The javadocs for `trim` indicate that any characters greater than '\u0020' will result in the original string being returned.  Thus, you probably have a value at the beginning or end that is greater than '\u0020'